# Get one line space at end of tweets in python

Tags: python, twitter

consider my code in python, minemaggi.txt file contains tweets and i am trying to remove stop words but in output file tweets are not comming in separate line.
    Also i want to remove all links from text file, what to do for that.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import codecs

import nltk

stopset = set(stopwords.words('english'))

writeFile = codecs.open("outputfile.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8')

with codecs.open("minemaggi.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
           line = f.read()
           new = '\n'
           tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
           tokens = [w for w in tokens if not w in stopset]
           for token in tokens:
                writeFile.write('{}{}'.format(' ', token))
           writeFile.write('{}'.format(new))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly add a newline character to the string you write to the file, like this:

```
writeFile.write('{}{}\n'.format(' ', token))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `' '.join()` to re-join the words and then write one line at a time:

```
with codecs.open("minemaggi.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    # loop over all lines in the input-file
    for line in f:
       # as before remove the stopwords ...
       tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
       tokens = [w for w in tokens if not w in stopset]
       # Rejoin the words separated by one space.
       line = ' '.join(tokens)
       # Write processed line to the output file.
       writeFile.write('{}\n'.format(line))
```

Hope that helps.